# JQuery functions with $ not running in head tag of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, squarespace

Due to Squarespace limitations, I can only add code via the Head tag. Whenever the script gets to the `$` part of JQuery, it doesn't seem to run it at all. I've tested with plentiful `console.log()`s and I notice that the webpage just skips over the `$(document)`, `$(".appoinment-type-name")`

Here is my code that I inject in the `<HEAD>` tag. This works when I just paste it in the console of the developer tools of Chrome.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
const token = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
var url = "https://ipinfo.io/json?token=" + token;
var userCountry = "";
var str ="";
var re = new RegExp('^IVA');


if (navigator.userAgent.match(/bot|spider/i)) {
    //Request is a bot, do nothing
} else {
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => runScript(data.country))
}

function runCountryCheck(country) {
        userCountry = country;
        console.log('User is in: ' + userCountry);
        return(country);
}
function removeRegex() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".appointment-type-name").each(function() {
        if (userCountry == "US") {
            str = $(this).html();
            if (str.match(re)) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.select-item-box').css('display', 'none');
            }
        } else {
            str = $(this).html();
            if (str.match(re)) {
                $(this).closest('.select-item-box').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
     }); 
    });
}

function runScript(country) {
    runCountryCheck(country);
    removeRegex();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you followed [these instructions](https://launchhubstudio.com/blog/squarespace-jquery)? Looks like you need to add jQuery to the "code injection" part of your settings.

Comment: If you look at the html - is the jquery library import <script tag before your attempted usage of the $?

Comment: @angel.bonev jQuery runs [`.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler) even when attached after the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You use `$(document).ready(function()` in a function, but It's an event run when your page is load (to be simple).

When you call the function you create the event, but not run script in this.
Just remove it on function and add ready event on your "if ... else".

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const token = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    var url = "https://ipinfo.io/json?token=" + token;
    var userCountry = "";
    var str ="";
    var re = new RegExp('^IVA');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/bot|spider/i)) {
            //Request is a bot, do nothing
        } else {
            fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => runScript(data.country))
        }
    });
</script>
```